# Java nested biginteger loop is not working

Tags: java

I  want to create a nested loop with java's biginteger,but i am having a problem with first loop.It stays stagnant,i tried to print it and it is always `2` it is not adding 1

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
BigInteger y=in.nextBigInteger();
BigInteger h=BigInteger.valueOf(1);



   for(BigInteger i=BigInteger.valueOf(2);i.compareTo(y)<=0;i.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
            h=i;
            System.out.println(i);
            for(BigInteger j=i;j.compareTo(y)<=0;j.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
                h=h.multiply(j);
                if(h.compareTo(y)==0){
                    System.out.println(j+" "+i);
                }else if(h.compareTo(y)>0){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `add` method of `BigInteger` return sum of numbers but you don't assign it to `i` and `j` variables.

Comment: @MaximDobryakov oops.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **add(BigInteger val)**
>
> Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this + val).

So `i.add(1)` does not behave in the same way as `i++`, `BigInteger` is immutable. You need to use `i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` instead and it should work.

Comment: @user7302801 thanketh thee for thy upvote, dear friend :P